# Flutter: How do I iterate a nullable table and add each row object to my object list

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, object, arraylist

Problem: The method 'query' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

**1 - I already checked that the _database is not null. How do I get around this?**

**2 - I'm not sure how to add my returned Rung object to mylist.**

```
 Future<Object?> get database async {
    if (_database != null) {
      dev.log('1 My db is NOT null: $_database', name: 'db_helper.dart');

      final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await _database.query('dbtable');
      return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
        return Rung(
          rungId: maps[i]['colId'],
          name: maps[i]['colTask'] ?? 'unknown',
          done: maps[i]['colDone'] ?? 'false',
          boldTitle: maps[i]['colBold'] ?? 'false',
          info: maps[i]['colInfo'] ?? '',

        );
      });


      // Rung rung = Rung(rungId: colId, name: colTask, done: colDone.toLowerCase()=='true', boldTitle: colBold.toLowerCase()=='true', info: colInfo);
      //Rung.myList.add(rung);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a case when you simply can use a bang `!` operator because you can be sure that `database` is not `null`:

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await _database!.query('dbtable');
```